# How to make a transparent plotted point

Tags: python, gnuplot, color-mapping

Here I am trying to achieve a radar effect on the spider/radar plot. Ideally I would like to have the plotted line dissapear given I time (for example over in 30 seconds the plotted line fades to transparent, I was thinking changing like sequential colormap or the plotted line is deleted/cleared)  but that may cause issues. So if the plotted line transition/fade to transparent would allow less clutter on the overall plot. It is possible but tricky for me..

```
set grid ls 10

set xtics axis format "" scale 0
set ytics axis format ""

set size square

set style line 9 lt 1 lw 2 pt 2 ps 2

set multiplot layout 1,2

plot 'somedata' using 1:5 t "" w lp ls 9
unset multiplot

pause 90
replot
```

How can I acheive this in Gnuplot?
In my reading I came accross something called Lerp/ Lerping colors, however I am not using Csharp or Unity.

output showing markers that need to fade/clear.
The main difference is that there would be just 1 not 9 as piture

[example of points that need to transition/fade to transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObeZL.png)

Comment: So you want a timesensitive filter. Wouldnt it be possible to use a pandas dataframe and insert your plot values with a time stamp and then compare that timestamp with the current time to determine in what time window to plot?

Comment: How does your data look like? Please show a few example lines. Will your datafile be constantly updated? And do you want gnuplot to run in a loop, wait for some time and plot the new datapoint and fade previous datapoints? Please clarify.

Comment: its the output in Gnuplot; not the data per say. It could be any data, the issue is at the time of plotting having the plotted result change/transition from solid color to transparent or be removed from plot. Gnuplots fuctions i am sure are capable of this as plot is written i a script shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your descriptions it still not clear to me what your expectations are. So, here is an example of what I would consider a "radar effect", i.e. fading away the colors.
It's setting transparent colors in a while loop (check `help while`) which you can stop by pressing `x` (check `help bind`).
The code can certainly be further optimized, but I hope you can adapt it to your needs.

**Code:**

```
### attempt to mimic a radar screen
reset session

# create some test landscape
set xrange [-8:8]
set yrange [-8:8]
set samples 50 
set isosamples 50
set contour
set cntrparam level 5
set table $Data 
    splot (sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x))*3
unset table
unset contour
set angle degrees
Angle(dx,dy) = dx==dx && dy==dy ? dx==0 ? dy==0 ? NaN : \
               abs(sgn(dy))*180-sgn(dy)*90 : dx<0 ? 180+atan(dy/dx) : \
               dy<0 ? atan(dy/dx)+360 : atan(dy/dx) : NaN
r(x,y) = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
set table $Contour
    plot $Data u (Angle($1,$2)):(r($1,$2)) index 1::1 
unset table

set size ratio 1
set polar
unset border
set border polar lc "green"
unset xtics
unset ytics
set format r ""
unset raxis
set rtics scale 0
set format t ""
set grid lw 2 lc "green"
set obj 1 rect from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 fc "black" behind     # black background

stop = 0
bind x "stop=1"

$Data <<EOD
45    5
0   4
123   3.5
325   3.5
EOD

unset key
set trange [0:360]
set rrange [0:8]

alpha(a,a0)    = int((1-exp(-real(a)/a0))*255)<<24       # transparency "decay" 
myBaseColor    = 0x00ff00
myColorA(a)    = myBaseColor + alpha(a,45)               # decay for radar "beam"
AngleDiff(a,b) = b>a ? b-a : 360-a+b
myColorB(a,b)  = myBaseColor + alpha(AngleDiff(a,b),220) # decay for data

a=90; step=5
while (!stop) {
    a = a<step ? a=a+360-step : a-step
    do for [i=0:180] {
        set obj 100+i circle at 0,0 size 8 arc [a+i:a+i+2] fs solid noborder fc rgb myColorA(i) behind
    }
    plot $Data u 1:2:(myColorB(a,$1)) w p pt 7 lc rgb var, \
         $Contour u 1:2:(myColorB(a,$1)) w l lc rgb var
}
### end of code
```

**Result:** (screen capture taken with ScreenToGif from wxt terminal)

[image]

Comment: Iam impressed just looking at what you have served here; l shall have a look. Exceptional.. A* just looking at the output alone.

Comment: @Randolp glad to hear that you like it. Oops, I just noticed that there is one while-loop too much. Probably, a remainder from experimenting, will modify the code. If the answer is helpful, do not forget to accept and/or upvote. If you have questions let me know.

Comment: is/can the passing green rotation on the scanner set to a time ie one 360 rotation sweep done within given time period?

Comment: @Randolp it's not a given time period. The drawing of the gradient is not very efficient. This is the loop from 0 to 180, drawing 181 semitransparent overlapping arcs. So, this is as fast as it can be plotted. I haven't checked the CPU usage. I'm not aware that you can easily draw a radial gradient with transparency otherwise. Do you need it within a certain given time period?

Comment: gnuplot is new to me, so how would I apply the example you provided to data I have to load in from a txt/csv file? In you example you set a datablock ie, ```$Data <<EOD
45    5
0   4
123   3.5
325   3.5
EOD```

Comment: @Randolp in the plot command, simply replace `$Data` by `'myFilename.txt'`. If you have a `csv` file you need to set `set datafile separator comma` beforehand, but then you have to make sure that `$Contour` also has comma as separator.

Comment: Is it possible to make the plot read only the newest/latest data in a data/csv file. ie only plot that point? by rereading the file using loop? and how can it be scripted to work with @theozh contribution/creation.

Comment: So, I understand you have a file which is getting larger and larger because new data is appended, but you only want to show the last, newest added point, correct?

Comment: Hi theozh correct, by only showing the newest point the rereading the dataflie would, statisfy the whole radar effect... Plus I am posting another question on gnuplot''How can static plot in gnuplot be converted to recieve updated data? your input and feedback on this is really needed. lifesaver. A**